# All list objects passed to a function at once

Tags: python, list, sympy

So i have a list with some objects:

```
from sympy import *
myList = [Interval(-oo,4), Interval(8,12), Interval(16,20)]
```

And i need to pass every object to a function at once, like this:

```
Union(Interval(-oo,4), Interval(8,12), Interval(16,20))
```

Is there an easy way to do it? I just can't see any way to do this.

Edit:
Specified the functions and objects I am working with

Comment: `myFunction(*myList)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called packing/unpacking of arguments and can indeed be done through the '*' operator

A detailed explanation and examples can be found [on this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/)

Comment: Yes it works! Didn't know this operator existed.